# Issues in Angular2 routing. Input to child not rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

```
route: /home

    <a routerLink="/dasbhoard"></a>

----------- 

route: /dashboard

<Dashboard>
  <slot  [slotObj]></slot>
  <carousel [carouselObj]></carousel>
</Dashboard>
```

I work on a project with a structure like the one above.
When user clicks on an anchor tag in the home component, he is ui routed to the dashboard component.
I have used the Resolve api to prefetch the objects for the dashboard component and these are in turn sent to the child components within dashboard: slot and carousel

Things work fine with the prefetch and page rendering. However, I notice that the Inputs to the child components on route change are not getting propagated.

Interestingly, if access the dashboard component directly or reload the page after navigation, everything works pretty well.

In short, on ui routing to Dashboard component, the child components do not render properly and no click action could be performed on them, but when the same page is reloaded, all functionalities work well.

Any help on this would help. I would want to avoid the hard navigation fix.

Comment: show full code, or create a plunker

Answer (score 1):

You should assign some value to input properties as below

```
<Dashboard>
  <slot  [slotObj]="slotObjwithValues"></slot>
  <carousel [carouselObj]="carouselObjwithValues"></carousel>
</Dashboard>
```

Comment: yes did. The code I mentioned above is just an outline. I did not want to paste complete component code.

Comment: so what exactly ur facing?

Comment: Aravind, is anything not clear with the description of this issue?

Comment: yes. I dont understand are you available in team viewer?